# How set UTF-8 in PDO class constructor for PHP PgSQL database

Tags: php, postgresql, utf-8, pdo

I want to set UTF8 for my PDO object. This class works correctly with MySQL.
I can't find an analog of `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8")` for PgSQL and I can't work with cyrillic symbols.

```
class oop{
private $host="localhost";
    private $user="xxxx";
    private $db="xxxx";
    private $pass="111111";
    private $conn;

public function __construct(){

    $this->conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->db,$this->user,$this->pass,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8") );

}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it appears to default to UTF-8 for me without explicitly setting it on a default Postgres installation. I can't find a documented switch for this either though ATM.

Comment: Why do you need all these private variables? $user, $db, $pass?

Comment: It's need because, mysql database didn't work with cyrillic symbols, before this command.

Comment: This private variable need because I use object oriented way and I change the databases from MySQL to PgSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see in section 21.2.3 on [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html), you can use one of the following two commands:

1. `SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'value';`
2. `SET NAMES 'value';`

where value = `UTF8`. Try using:

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8';
```

or

```
SET NAMES 'UTF8';
```

Comment: How I use this in PDO?

Answer (score 4):

Let me point out the comment by xmedeko, that is absolute right:

```
pg_connect("host=localhost options='--client_encoding=UTF8'");
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php

Using charset=utf8 is working (only) with mysql...

Comment: He is using pdo