# What is PostgreSQL equivalent of MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND?

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework2

With zend2 Currently I use (mysql) But I will change to use postgres

Code:

```
 <?php
return array(
   'db' => array(
      'driver'         => 'Pdo',
      'dsn'            => 'pgsql:dbname=sample;host=127.0.0.1',
      'driver_options' => array(
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8'
      ),
   ),
   'service_manager' => array(
      'factories' => array(
         'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory'
      ),
   ),

    'module_layouts' => array(
       'Application' => 'layout/layout.phtml',
       'Admin' => 'layout/layout.phtml',
   ),

);
```

Is there a `PostgreSQL` equivalent of

```
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")?
```

Comment: Note that in Postgres, the default charset and collation isn't latin/swedish, but utf8_ci (ci as in case insensitive, if memory serves). So issuing such a command is normally not needed to begin with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250167/how-set-utf-8-in-pdo-class-constructor-for-php-pgsql-database