# Inserting data with PDO -- Error UTF8

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

I have a table with the following columns:

`users(
  id SERIAL,
  username VARCHAR(20),
  password VARCHAR(64),
  salt VARCHAR(32),
  name VARCHAR(50),
  joined TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
  grupo INTEGER
 )`

The database encoding is UTF8.

Pdo connection:

```
private function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('pgsql:host=' . Config::get('pgsql/host') . ';port=' . Config::get('pgsql/port') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('pgsql/db') . ';user=' . Config::get('pgsql/username'). ';password=' . Config::get('pgsql/password'));
            $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I'm using PDO, and my script is the following, to insert data:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()){
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
           $this->_query->execute($params);
        }
}
```

The sql passed is the following:

```
INSERT INTO users(username, password, salt, name, joined, grupo) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And the array passed is:

```
Array (             [0] => nath 
                    [1] => 81033b63c09fd9104977fdb0ef70b5dc627fd9a6e90d0d400706603def8c22a6 
                    [2] => KwjWC57AO0Gh1VvSUuJpDMNkEiraBzFL 
                    [3] => Nathália 
                    [4] => 2014-03-06 19:35:01 
                    [5] => 1 )
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERRO: invalid byte sequence invalid for UTF encode. "UTF8": 0xe1 0x6c 0x69
```

PS: If I type Nathalia instead of Nathália it works perfectly.

Trying to figure out what was going on, I inserted field by field, like this:

```
if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username) VALUES(?)"){
            $this->_query->execute(array('nath'));
}
```

And it worked ok. Then I replaced `username` with `password` and `array('nath')` with `array('81033b63c09fd9104977fdb0ef70b5dc627fd9a6e90d0d400706603def8c22a6')` and the same for the other fields.

Everything worked perfectly when I inserted field by field. Any clues of what is going on?

Comment: What does your `PDO` constructor look like? Did you add the `charset` param or run `SET NAMES` after connection (and before anyone says this is Postgres and not MySQL, they support the same connection charset parameters)? See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18250296/283366

Comment: @Phil I'll add up there

Comment: possible duplicate of [How set UTF-8 in PDO class constructor for PHP PgSQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250167/how-set-utf-8-in-pdo-class-constructor-for-php-pgsql-database)

Comment: @Phil I tried to set UTF-8 in PDO connection `$this->_pdo = new PDO('pgsql:host=' . Config::get('pgsql/host') . ';port=' . Config::get('pgsql/port') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('pgsql/db') . ';charset=UTF-8' . ';user=' . Config::get('pgsql/username'). ';password=' . Config::get('pgsql/password'));`  and I got this: `SQLSTATE[08006] [7] invalid connection option "charset"`

Comment: Then try running a `SET NAMES` query immediately after connection. Also, I believe it's `UTF8` (no hyphen)

Comment: Like this `$this->_pdo->query("SET NAMES UTF8")` ?

Comment: I got the same UTF8 error :/

Comment: And I think it might be another problem, instead of database encoding, because if that was true, despite of I insert field by field, it wouldn't work. And the fact is that if I insert field by field it works.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is specific about the problem:

> 0xe1 0x6c 0x69

0xe1 is `á` in iso-8859-1, not in utf-8.

The other two bytes represent characters in the US-ASCII range (`l` and `i`) so they share the same byte-representation in iso-8859-1 and utf-8.

Your script is sending `iso-8859-1` encoded text instead of `utf-8` encoded text. You should question where you get the `Nathália` string from, and how it's supposed to be encoded.

If it's supposed to be in `utf-8` then it's a bug from the producer of that string. If it's supposed to be in ISO-latin, then your script must apply [`utf8_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) to it before feeding it to the `utf-8` database connection.