# How to pass a latin1 charset associative array from php to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, character-encoding, associative-array

The problem is that I have latin1 charset in db. The default output is utf-8 in php.
even when i am using php iconv, it returns null as the new string is supposedly already utf-8.

Converting DB would need downtime.

I cant use json_encode because the string is malformed utf-8 containing �.

I need an alternative to temporarily fix the issue without having to migrate the db.

I need to transfer the associative array back to JS. I am using Ajax for getting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the encoding, prior to passing the data on to `json_encode` (which really needs UTF8 encoded strings). Using [the `mb_convert_encoding` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) will do:

```
$utf8String = mb_convert_encoding(
    $sourceString,
    'UTF8',
    '<src encoding>' //in your case: ISO-8859-1
);
```

Meanwhile, work out a strategy of how you are going to convert your DB to UTF-8, because it'll save you a lot of pain endlessly juggling different encodings throughout your project.

Answer (score 0):

Set your driver's encoding (client) explicitely to UTF-8.

Examples with:

- [PDO/PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18250313/1446005)
- [PDO/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361485/1446005)